# Paypal payment Integration via "Buy Now" button return url issue

Tags: paypal

Friends I just create link url using the button code as following

> https://*****.com/paypal/return_process.php?cmd=_ext-enter&redirect_cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=******&no_note=1&lc=USA&currency_code=USD&bn=PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest&first_name=Customer's First Name&last_name=Customer's Last Name&payer_email=customer@example.com&item_name=10 Seats&item_number=123456&item_price=20&return=https://www.******.com/paypal/return_process.php&submit=submit&tx=tduT3MGZdRDqTeLfy9ye2UvbbO1Tf_fQNcQj015DLQNnYjZC7eSIa8o_Nn8.

It works great with sandbox but when i am trying to put it online the return url not working after payment complete it redirected to "https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/merchant" this url.

I did all the setting in palpal account i.e Website Preference setting auto return on with the correct return url.

I am trying this with putting product price 0.02 dollar if someone have solution for above problem OR is there any error with my code please tell me...

Comment: could you put return URL like: 
https://yourdomainname.com/pagename.php

Comment: Yes exactly
return=https://www.******.com/paypal/return_process.php

Comment: could you see the following answer?

Comment: "could you see the following answer? - Pradoshi Mukherjee".

Comment: Cant see your answer.